# Heroku + S3 AWS + Django != No Images

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I tried to put my app online, but it seems that image files don't show up. Maybe you can help? I have required images in my bucket in S3 AWS, but still nothing appears. Although when I try to open the image on the webside I am sent to the amazon website. And tehn I get this message:

> `InvalidRequest`  The authorization
>   mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use
>   AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.  8CF0C70490DEFEE2
>   
>   dtBKlPBbw5L6pM6mGyd4YaqC4amay/c2tccfhhStjujVGG2qdrvQwD6vGloJZWQle9A5Cwr3Rws=

```
Here is my settings.py

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

os.makedirs(STATIC_TMP, exist_ok=True)

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "####"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="####"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME="####"

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MEDIA_URL is not correct.

Try something like this (I am assuming you want you use for static resources and media):

```
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "my_bucket"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

STATIC_LOCATION = "resources/"
MEDIA_LOCATION = "media/"

AWS_BUCKET_ACL = "public-read"
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "your-bucket-region"

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com"


STATIC_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}"
MEDIA_URL = f"https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIA_LOCATION}/"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but here is a repetition. You wrote two times `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL`. Can you correct this?

Comment: Ok, now I got this message, when I try to access image `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>A868FC94C6274D47</RequestId>
<HostId>
KSDU9jrCp3Gwlo4sGb0YIcS5xgZe39FLQRcwwW9691LokMLOUWTnz0fT6qyLkYy799HbieSRFV8=
</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: oh sorry. There you go.

Comment: It is probably something with your bucket access. Make sure that the credentials you are using have access to the bucket, and the bucket cors are correctly set.

Comment: Hmm... I believe I did it right. Please tell me. AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = `us-eas-2` is it how it supposed to be written?

Comment: `us-east-2`, yes. Have you enable cors on the bucket?

Comment: Yes, this one and still nothing. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`

Comment: your bucket contains public images that you want to show on your website, so you need to make your bucket publicly readable.